# How to convert string to dateTime2(7) T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I am trying to insert `createdDatetime` into a table.

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
DECLARE @CreatedDatetime DATETIME2(7) = CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), '2018-11-13 10:57:13.5235756')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table](CreatedDatetime) 
VALUES (@CreatedDatetime)

SELECT Updated = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `121` to denote `ODBC canonical`. See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
Declare @CreatedDatetime datetime2(7) = CONVERT(datetime2(7), '2018-11-13 10:57:13.5235756', 121)
```